# Append data to formData object

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I seem not to get additionally data added to "formData".

First i add my input file:

```
var form = $('#uploadForm')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

var input = $("#uploadPhoto")[0];
//Add input file data to formData
formData.append(input.name, input.files[0]);
```

This works just fine.
And my PHP `var_dump` after "ajax call" results:

```
array(1) {
  ["uploadPhoto"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "1.xls"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(40) "..../tmp/phpmyn3E1"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(42799)
  }
}
```

Now i'd like to add some extra data for passing on to the php script:

```
formData.append('usr', selectedUsr);
formData.append(input.name, selectedUsr);
formData.append('usr', 'usr: '+ selectedUsr);
```

When i now check my PHP var_dump, there is no "usr" data in array.
Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When u append:

```
formData.append('usr', selectedUsr);
```

You cannot access the object with `$_FILES['uploadPhoto']`

Instead i access with `$_POST`

So my solution was:

```
//JS
formData.append('usr', selectedUsr);
//PHP
$usr = $_POST['usr'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are checking only `$_FILES` , also check post data `print_r($_POST)`